# Не прописывать дважды

Tags: javascript

```
fetch('/ajax/', {body: FormAdd(pr), method: 'POST'})
    .then(r => { return r.json()})
    .then(d => eval(d))
```

Каким образом, сделать так, чтобы 'then' не прописывать дважды. То есть в первом then сразу выполнить eval(d)

Comment: никаким. `.jdon` возвращает Promise, следовательно результат можно получить только в `then`.

Comment: а зачем вообще делать `eval`, если у тебя уже есть `json`?

Comment: В php отдаю die(json_encode("alert('ssdf')"));

Comment: Он не исполняется,  возвращает как строчку, эту строчку и вставляю в eval. Каким образом возможно не использовать eval, так чтобы код в ответе сработал?

Comment: ты используешь не верный подход. Если ты хочешь загрузить и выполнить скрипт - используй тег script.

Comment: Мне необходимо исполнить js тогда когда ответ от сервера получен.

Comment: То есть, внести изменения в html документ, когда ответ приходит. В ответе целиком и js и html, просто исполняю строчку и все. Это удобно

Comment: Тогда чем не устраивает уже используемый код?